# Sharepoint Search Crawler & robots.txt

Tags: search, 2007

Does anyone know how to set up a robots.txt file to allow the sharepoint crawler to index content on a sharepoint site, but disallow all other bots (like google, yahoo, etc...)?  Or in other words, what user agent does the sharepoint crawler use to identify itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not know this, but after a 2 second Bing I found this:
http://www.wssdemo.com/Lists/Resources/DispFormOld.aspx?ID=2226

Comment: Cool, trying it now in the robots.txt.